# String.Format crashes when passing obj[] from generic[] parameter

Tags: c#, .net, generics, casting

Ran into an interesting problem today, I changed some of my error generating methods to accept generically typed arrays as parameters instead of explicit string[]. However, when I tried to pass the generic parameter arrays to a String.Format call later in the method, it crashes it, and trying to access the array from within String.Format only returns 1 thing in the collection: the collection type.

Example:

```
// Just a small snippet of affected code
// Passing in 1 and a new string[] { "FIRST", "SECOND" }
public void SetErrorProperties(int errorCode, string[] paramArgs)
{
    Dictionary<int, string> ErrorMessages = new Dictionary<int, string>(){ {1, "TEST MESSAGE: {0} {1}"} };
    err_msg += String.Format(ErrorMessages.Index[errorCode], paramArgs);
    //works just fine, returns "TESTING MESSAGE: FIRST SECOND"  
}

public void SetErrorProperties<T>(int errorCode, T[] paramArgs)
{
    Dictionary<int, string> ErrorMessages = new Dictionary<int, string>(){ {1, "TEST MESSAGE: {0} {1}"} };
    err_msg += String.Format(ErrorMessages.Index[errorCode], paramArgs);
    // now this returns an error of Format Exception: Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list

    // accessing array directly paramArgs[0] returns "FIRST" and paramArgs[1] returns "SECOND"
    // However, String.Format("{0}", paramArgs) returns "System.String[]" and String.Format ("{0} {1}", paramArgs) return the index exception
}
```

Does anyone know why this happens when String.Format accepts an object[] as the second parameter? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why this happens when String.Format accepts an `object[]` as the second parameter?

This is exactly why it is happening - `T[]` is not necessarily an `object[]`, so unless `T` happens to be `object` in a particular call, the cast fails.

You can fix this by converting to `object[]` inside the call, like this:

```
err_msg += String.Format(ErrorMessages.Index[errorCode], paramArgs.Cast<object>().ToArray());
```

Comment: ah ok thanks for clearing up the confusion. So is T in this context just treated as some generic...."thing" that isn't an object?

Comment: @DDushaj `T` may or may not correspond to `object`, depending on the way the method is called. The actual type is supplied at compile time: if you call `SetErrorProperties<object>(1, 2, "hello", 45.67)` your call would succeed, because this makes `T` an `object`.